# How to detect when action popup gets closed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to trigger some code when page action or browser action popup gets closed. I tried listening to `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` events on `<body>` or `window` but they never fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug, but a chromium developer posted a workaround.

http://crbug.com/31262#c13

Answer (score 1):

As looks like there is no straight forward solution, this is what I ended up doing if anyone interested.

Periodically ping background page from the popup, and if background page is not received ping within some time period, it triggers required action. Works like a time bomb :)

In background page:

```
var timeoutId = 0;
function popupPing() {
    if(timeoutId != 0) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        popupClosed();
        timeoutId = 0;
    }, 1000);
}

function popupClosed() {
    //...
}
```

In popup:

```
ping();
function ping() {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().popupPing();
    setTimeout(ping, 500);
}
```

(note that popup pings 2 times faster than "trigger" time in background page)

Comment: Although I really hope there is a better answer (and if there isn't, we should file a bug), this is a pretty cool hack. A sort of dead man's switch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man's_switch